# PHP Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found

Tags: php, windows, iis-7

I'm getting this error after upgrading PHP to v. 5.5.1:

```
Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ndsystems\database_engine\mssql_engine.php on line 184
```

Line 184 in mssql_engine.php file:

```
$this->COMConnection = new COM('ADODB.Connection');    //line 184
try {
    $this->COMConnection->Open($connectionString);
    $this->RetrieveServerVersion();
} catch (com_exception $e) {
    $this->lastError = $e->getMessage();
    $result = false;
}
return $result;
```

Environment is Windows 2008 R2 SP1, IIS 7

Things I tried:

1. Added this at the end of php.ini:

   ```
   [PHP_COM_DOTNET]

   extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
   ```
2. Added `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` in [PHP] section of php.ini
3. Rebooted IIS and also rebooted server itself.
4. Downgraded PHP to 5.3.27

Nothing seems to work. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Put <?php phpinfo() ?> in a test php script, open in your browser. See if the "com_dotnet" section is there and if "COM support" is "enabled."

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using ADO when you could use PHP's `mssql` SQL Server client library?

Comment: @Dai - I don't know much about php so I used sqlmaestro's php generator for MSSQL database.

Comment: @jszobody - The only reference to com_dotnet I see is in Configure Command section:
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze

Answer (score 3):

In addition to adding

```
[PHP_COM_DOTNET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

to your `php.ini` file, you have to tell PHP where to look for the extension, and to enable extensions.

To tell PHP where to look for extensions on Windows just uncomment (remove the leading `;`) following line:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

To enable extensions set the enable flag to On:

```
enable_dl = On
```

Comment: OP probably might NOT want to `enable_dl = on` , as he uses IIS, and php.ini says: `The dl() function does NOT work properly in multithreaded servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is automatically disabled on them.`