# Fatal Error Class COM not found with extension php_com_dotnet installed

Tags: php, com, environment-variables

I've recently installed PHP 5.6.37 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.

PHP folder has been copied from a Windows 10 machine where it works fine.
Because it isn't a proper installation, I've manually added `C:\php` to the `PATH` environment variable.

When I try to run some code which uses COM classes, it throws:

> ```
> Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in XXXX on line 42
> ```

Looking for a solution and I found this answers:

- [Class 'COM' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678325/class-com-not-found)
- [PHP Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240521/php-fatal-error-class-com-not-found?rq=1)

But none of those worked for me, because both (extensions and `php.ini` file) were fine, since it worked on the Windows 10 machine before.

Where the issue could be then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PHPRC Environment Variable was missing

```
PHPRC = C:\php
```

---

After looking around a little bit more, I found the problem was caused by the **manual copy** of the PHP folder, because I've skipped the installation with the `.msi` file. The installation file not only add PHP folder to `PATH` variable but it also creates a new variable called `PHPRC` which determines where the **Runtime Configuration** is located (`C:\php` by default).